# Ubuntu on VM windows hangs during start up

Tags: mount, virtualbox

I recently installed Ubuntu ver 18.04.1 on VirtualBox (Windows 10) and after realizing 10 GB wasn't a large enough disk image I mounted a new 50 GB image to the system. Now when I start the machine it loads a little then hangs on 
"Started User Manager for UID 121."
I don't know where to go from here and no one seems to have the same issue on Google.